# IndexError: string index out of range while working with random module

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, random, index-error

I'm making password generator in python and this is the error I'm stuck with. Here's my code:

```
import random

symbols = 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm'
choosing_len = int(input('> '))


def password_generating():

    def random_letter():
        zero = 0
        lenght = len(symbols)
        letter_index = random.randint(zero, lenght+1)
        random_symbol = symbols[letter_index]

        return random_symbol


    password = []

    while len(password) != choosing_len:
        key = [random_letter()]
        password = password + key

    print(''.join(password))


password_generating()
```

I have to say the error shows up very randomly (it almost never shows on 6). I tried to analyze it step by step and removing some code parts. nothing helps.

Comment: Please update your question with the full traceback.

Comment: What does the error state?

Comment: This is unrelated to your problem, but because using `+` on lists is rather slow, consider building `password` by doing `password.append(random_letter())` instead. Or even `password = [random_letter() for i in range(choosing_len)]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is here:

```
letter_index = random.randint(zero, lenght+1)
```

Unlike `range(a, b)`, that gives numbers from a upto b, not including b, i.e. `a <= x < b`, [`random.randint(a, b)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) gives a random integer from `a <= x <= b`. To correct this, we can just use

```
letter_index = random.randint(zero, lenght - 1)
```

Or even better,

```
random_symbol = random.choice(symbols)
```

Comment: Also, maybe consider renaming the variable to `length`